# How to create a reference field in a document from Dart code - Flutter Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Cloud Firestore you can create documents with different types of fields, one of them is the Reference field.
I want to create a Reference field from Dart code, but it always creates it as a string.

I have a collection called "usuarios" (users) and I want to create a subcollection inside that collection called "categoriasFavoritas" (favourite cathegories), where there are listed the favourites cathegories of the user.
I have this code:

```
    CollectionReference<Object?> referenciaCategoriasFavoritas = bbdd.collection('/usuarios/${docUsuario.id}/categoriasFavoritas');

    listaCategoriasFavoritas.forEach((idCategoria) {
      var docCategoriaFavorita = referenciaCategoriasFavoritas.doc();
      var ref = bbdd.collection('categorias').doc();
      var jsonCategoriaFavorita = {'idCategoria': ref.path}; //Here
      docCategoriaFavorita.set(jsonCategoriaFavorita);
```

I create the subcollection "referenciaCategoriasFavoritas" inside the user document and, as I have the list of the favourite cathegories ids (listaCategoriasFavoritas), I just want to put those ids as a reference of the "categorias" (cathegories) collection in the subcollection I've created.
The part when I put the //Here comment es where I create that reference field.

I've tried this option too, but it doesn't work neither:

```
    var jsonCategoriaFavorita = {'idCategoria': '/categorias/$idCategoria'};
```

It's saved as a string field, and not as a Reference field, as you can create directly in Cloud Firestore:

[Field created as a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVRA1.png)

Does anyone know how to create reference fields from the code?

Comment: I cannot try it  at the moment, but `var jsonCategoriaFavorita = {'idCategoria': ref};` should work.

Comment: Yes! You're right, I needed to put the hole document reference to get that kind of field. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Renaud commented, you need to set a `DocumentReference` object as the value of the field. The database will then store that reference, and display its path in the Firebase console.

So:

```
var jsonCategoriaFavorita = {'idCategoria': ref};
```

Comment: Yeaah, you're right, it wasn't the ref.path but the hole document reference. Thank you so much!